# How to retrieve Drupal taxonomies with a SQL query?

Tags: sql, drupal-7, ubercart

I have developed a music store using *Drupal 7* and *Ubercart 3*, I'm using *JasperReports* (*iReport*) to build reports. I'm retrieve multiple Taxonomy terms contained in taxonomy_index table which belong to a certain node, so I can display in the report.

For example node id 13 has 3 terms.

[image]

My challenge is my current query only shows one term. May you please help with my query to show more terms.

```
SELECT
     taxonomy_term_data.`name` AS taxonomy_term_data_name,
     taxonomy_vocabulary.`name` AS taxonomy_vocabulary_name,
     uc_order_products.`qty` AS uc_order_products_qty,
     uc_order_products.`price` AS uc_order_products_price,
     node.`type` AS node_type,
     node.`title` AS node_title,
     uc_orders.`created` AS uc_orders_created
FROM
     `uc_order_products` uc_order_products INNER JOIN `node` node ON uc_order_products.`nid` = node.`nid`
     INNER JOIN `taxonomy_index` taxonomy_index ON node.`nid` = taxonomy_index.`nid`
     INNER JOIN `taxonomy_term_data` taxonomy_term_data ON taxonomy_index.`tid` = taxonomy_term_data.`tid`
     INNER JOIN `taxonomy_vocabulary` taxonomy_vocabulary ON taxonomy_term_data.`vid` = taxonomy_vocabulary.`vid`
     INNER JOIN `uc_orders` uc_orders ON uc_order_products.`order_id` = uc_orders.`order_id`
WHERE
     taxonomy_term_data.`tid` = 11
```

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: @AlexK I have edited my question to make more sense.

Comment: What is your problem: to write the query or to construct the report's template?

Comment: Writing a query to return all the fields I need in the report